# Doing a conditional update in dynamodb with the data model

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to do a conditional update of an item in dynamodb using the data model as you can with the [document model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemsExample.html)?  If there isn't a way to do a conditional update does the .Net SDK have a method to convert an object into an UpdateItemRequest object?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [UpdateExistingAttributeConditionally](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelDotNetItemsExample.html) method for an example of how to perform a conditional update on an item in DynamoDB using the .NET SDK data model. You can also [set a ConditionExpression using the document model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKMidLevel.html#UpdateMidLevelDotNet) when using the midlevel sdk for .NET.